# Discord.py AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'server'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm having an issue in which I'm getting the error AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'server' however how I have put `ctx.server:` in my code. I thought this would work I though I was missing ctx from the coroutine signature.

Heres how I'm trying to do it.

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)                
async def unpin(self, ctx):
    """Listen for a message then unpin any other messages older than 7 days"""
    server = ctx.server
    messages = await self.bot.pins_from(self.bot.get_channel('490899209067823135'))
    if server:
        for msg in messages:
            if (datetime.now() - msg.timestamp).days > 7:
                try:
                   await self.bot.unpin_message(msg)
                   print ("Unpinned")

                except discord.Forbidden:
                   print("No permissions to do that!")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `channel = self.bot.get_channel()`

Here is what I have done for you. Please note that Discord limits you to 50 pins per channel so you'll need cursory check is done to evaluate if the channel has room for the incoming pin.

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    """Listen for message then pin it"""
    try:
        server = message.server
        channel = self.bot.get_channel('1234567890') 
        pins = await self.bot.pins_from(channel)
        if message.channel == channel and message.type != 
          discord.MessageType.pins_add:
            if len(pins) == 50:
                await self.bot.unpin_message(pins[-1])
            await self.bot.pin_message(message)            

    except discord.Forbidden:
        print("No permissions to do that!")
```

Comment: Why would you use an `on_message` event all of a sudden when the question was why `ctx.server` in a command doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctx.message.server` instead
According to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/ja/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=context#discord.ext.commands.Context.prefix) `Context` has no attribute `server`

Comment: I just get this error: 'Message' object has no attribute 'server'.